# how to use tcpdump to capture LAN packets which are not from or destined to my PC?

Tags: networking, tcpdump

I'm using wifi for network access. I'm doing an experiment with my smartphone to do some experiment and I want to capture packets which are from my smartphone. My idea is to use my laptop with tcpdump to capture the packets.

Comment: tried wireshark?

Comment: @Xen2050, I tried with promiscuous mode , but it can't capture the packets which are not destined to or from the PC where Wireshark is, except some ARP or IGMP packets

Answer (score 0):

On a properly configured, up-to-date (WPA) Wifi system, a Wifi client (the smartphone) & the AP talks over a secured channel that no other stations can decode.

You have the following options:

- capture the traffic on the Wifi AP (or some other network equipment the traffic touches, eg your Internet router, if the traffic is between the smartphone & the Internet)
- capture the traffic on the smartphone (if there exists software for this...)
- persuade your equipments (smartphone/Wifi AP) to route the traffic through your laptop (for this, you'd have to change the default router of the smartphone to be your laptop, and configure some kind of IP NAT service on your laptop so that incoming traffic from the smartphone gets its source IP address changed to that of the laptop - this way the replies will be routed back through the laptop)
- change the Wifi security configuration so that the laptop is able to decode the traffic of other stations seen on the Wifi network (WPA is too secure, you either have to use no security or WEP; this may or may not a trivial job as these options are not considered secure and your equipments might refuse to use unsecure configuration)

Comment: Or get the password for the network, capture with Wireshark/TShark or some other sniffer that can decode WPA traffic when given the password or capture into a binary capture file and read that file in that sniffer, make sure that you capture the initial EAPOL handshake for the Wi-Fi client in question, and supply the password to the sniffer.

Comment: no, I don't have intention to decode the packets, I just want to check the IP address and TCP seq number, TCP options, blabla.